# Installation of React Native, Node.js, Chocolate

Tags: react-native, nodes, npm-install

I'm just a new in React Native. I want to install all the files or dependencies required for React  Native and I want to put it all in D:/ disk even the React Native project.

Answer (score 0):

From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

Comment: Is that gonna give me the location path that I want?

Comment: if you run those commands from that directory. the create-react-native-app will be installed globally

Comment: Okay then. How can i setup the location path of my React Native project when creating?